# Display different icon for empty folders

Tags: elfinder

There is a way to display a different icon for empty folders?

Actually, I can work with the back-end code to add a favicon.ico file, when the folder became non-empty after an insert or move operation, and remove them when the folder gets empty after a move or delete operation.

But this sounds as a complicate process.

Answer (score 1):

> https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/issues/1643

This is possible with connector main option [`bind`](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options-2.1#bind).

e.g. - add CSS class name `elfinder-dir-empty` to empty folder of the LocalFileSystem volume.

```php
function setEmptyFolderCssName($cmd, &$result, $args, $elfinder, $volume) {
    if ($volume && $volume instanceof elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem && $result) {
        $key = '';
        if (! empty($result['files'])) {
            $key = 'files';
        } else if (! empty($result['tree'])) {
            $key = 'tree';
        } else if (! empty($result['added'])) {
            $key = 'added';
        }
        if ($key) {
            foreach($result[$key] as $i => $file) {
                if (isset($file['mime']) && $file['mime'] === 'directory') {
                    $path = $volume->getPath($file['hash']);
                    if (($items = scandir($path)) && count($items) === 2) {
                        $result[$key][$i]['csscls'] = 'elfinder-dir-empty';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$opts = array(
    'lbind' => array( 'open tree parent mkdir' => array( 'setEmptyFolderCssName' ) ),
    'roots'  => array(
        array(
            'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem',
            'path'   => '/path/to/files/',
            'URL'    => 'http://localhost/to/files/'
        )
    )
);

// run elFinder
$connector = new elFinderConnector(new elFinder($opts));
$connector->run();
```